# Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0' not found

Tags: java, maven

I am having problems with the *maven-compiler-plugin* version.
It's underlined in red color, when I hover over the `<version>3.8.0</version>` field, a pop-up with below error appears:

> Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0' not found

Here down my plugin declaration section:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After executing the maven project:

````
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  25.886 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-19T22:13:16+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project untitled19: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException```
````

Comment: Which IDE are you using?
When you execute Maven from the command line (or within the IDE) what is the output you get?

Comment: Please try to run on plain command line I suspect some warnings about not found artifacts etc. Can you write which Maven version you are using ? And post the full log output here..

Comment: tmarwen @khmarbaise i have edited the post and added the execution and where i got the failure. Also im using Apache Maven 3.6.3

Comment: Sorry but that output of exec-maven-plugin is completely unrelated to the rest of the question? and shows already the issue `The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or invalid `...?

Comment: well thats the only error i get, im completely new to maven

Answer (score 0):

For my part, try adding a new dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And that's it, check the version and try it.